Can FluentBit consume an ActiveMQ queue?
I have an ActiveMQ with MQTT enabled. Is it possible for FluentBit to consume an ActiveMQ queue? I tried using this but Fluentbit is unable to start because ActiveMQ is already using the port 1833. If I stop ActiveMQ and use mosquitto_pub to publish a message, it works as in the example.
My ultimate goal is to have FluentBit consuming the ActiveMQ queue/topic.
